# How do I set the preferred units for quantity types programmatically using Apples' HealthKit?

Tags: ios, healthkit

Is there a way to set the preferred units for specific quantity types programmatically?

preferredUnitsForQuantityTypes will return units that are already set via the Health app. Is there a similar call to set these values programmatically?

I am integrating user preferences from Health app right into my app so that there is a seamless experience for the user.  In the use case when User has never used Health app, and therefore has never setup their preferred units, I don't want the User to have to leave my App, run Health app, set their preferred units for each quantity, then come back to my app and continue their setup process.  While Health app may initially reference the Local default settings, these may not ultimately be what the user likes to see.

If there isn't a way to set these types outside of health app, what is the recommended flow for this?

Comment: If the available property is read-only, then most likely it's up to the user to chose their preferred units and you shouldn't be allowed to changed that. I don't think it is the best choice to try to outsmart the user.

Comment: To clarify, the user will set these settings right from my app - my app requires a small subset (2-3).  I don't know if these are read-only, I can't find information either way.  Please see Use case scenario mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API to change the user's preferred units for a quantity type. Preferred units may only be changed in the Health app by the user.